# Is $[x,0]=0 $ for all $x \in L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I am following a book for lie algebra and i am completely new to this field. I have to show following
Let L be a lie algebra with [,] as bracket on it. Actually I want to show that $\{0\}$ is ideal in L. For this purpose all I need is to show that
$\forall\; x\; in\; L \; and \;y=0 \in \{0\} $ we have $[x,y=0]=0$.
I am not sure how to argue? what I am thinking is $[x,0]
=0$ for all x in L but how? . Which I have not read in book. Need guidance. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $(x,y)\mapsto[x,y]$ is bilinear. In particular, for each $x\in L$, the map $y\mapsto[x,y]$ is linear. And *every* linear map maps $0$ into $0$.

Comment: So nice. So this means can I conclude for every bilinear map say $\phi: U \times V \rightarrow W$ that $ \phi(u,0)=0\; \forall u\; \in \; U$ and $ \phi(0,v)=0\; \forall v\; \in \; V$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank so you much it helps a lot a lot !!!

Comment: Thank You so much sir